# how to choose the first letter of a word?

Tags: python, tkinter, random

how do i make a function statement that only chooses the first letter of a choosed word?

```
def Example():
    WordChoose = random.choice(self.ThreeWords)
    if WordChoose == 'a':
            print('good')
    else:
       print('bad')
       print(WordChoose)
```

im try to make a hangman type of game but i can seem to get the first letter of a work
i tried 'split()' and 'len()'
but nothing worked!

i already tried

```
split()
```

and

```
len()
```

Comment: `if WordChoose[0] == 'a': ...`?

Comment: how did you try using those? are you familiar with slicing? simply do `word[0]` to get the first character of variable `word` (should be string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always choose the first letter of any word, you can try this
`word[0]` , where `word` is your string. In python any string can be accessed with indexing.

```
>>> word = 'were'
>>> word[0]
'w'
>>>
```

In case you need a sample code for the hangman game , here is a link : [python hangman game](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-word-guessing-game/)

Answer (score 1):

`split` and `len` can do it, but you can it at much easier way:

```
def Example():
    WordChoose = random.choice(self.ThreeWords)
    if WordChoose[0] == 'a': #add the `[0]` after WordChoose...
            print('good')
    else:
       print('bad')
       print(WordChoose)
```